# How do I add an attribute in Mobile Patent Suits?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, svg, d3.js

I want to add a name/text to the connection between two nodes using [Mobile Patent Suits](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292)

```
           is used by
i.e Oracle ----------> Google
```

Nodes are created here:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});
```

but looking at the code that creates the graph, there is no function where I can insert something like

```
node.append("title")
    .text("my text");
```

(and also adding this it doesn't work).
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append textPath to the link.

```
var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "link-group")
    .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "link" + i;})
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

svg.selectAll(".link-group").append("text")
    .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("startOffset",function(d,i){return 8/20;})
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){return "#link"+i;})
    .text("hello")
    ;
```

Here's an example:

http://vida.io/documents/FTC9fmmEP2Geg735z

Comment: Ok. This is what I want.. but I have a problem now.. If I put it into my code, arrows disappears.. so I tried to use the solution taken from that example you linked, but the graph doesn't appear anymore..

Comment: You may have an error in the code. Can you post your code on vida.io?

Comment: I have some problem to use vida.io.. here's the code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pUa3H/ the file in the filesystem is saved as `[{"source": "cur", "target": "next", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "next", "target": "next2", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "cur2", "target": "next2", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "next3", "target": "next2", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "next2", "target": "cur4", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "cur5", "target": "next", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "cur2", "target": "next4", "rel": "suit"},
{"source": "cur3", "target": "next3", "rel": "suit"}
]`

Comment: Hm, maybe there's an error with your fs loading. I paste your var links data in the code and it works. http://vida.io/documents/NJDNuL674ukHpu7uz

Comment: Uhm.. the graph is shown if I delete #canvas and insert body into `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")` .. but the graph has now the name in the connection but a line appears instead of an arrow.. Have to try and try :) Thanks btw :)!! You were really helpful!

Comment: vida.io uses #canvas so you'll have to change to your drawing area when using outside.

Comment: StackOverflow suggests moving to chat but you don't have enough points. Send me an email dnprock@gmail.com.